# Set a single color gradient with R's mapview

Tags: r, mapview

I'm trying to setup a mapview of some Census data and am struggling to color the areas (Census tracts in my case) using a single color gradient. Example would be coloring light blue for the lowest value, and then dark blue for the highest value. I can get mapview to color using random code blocks I've come across the web but I can't figure out the documentation to set one color gradient. Here are some that have worked:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
tracts <- tracts("IN", "St. Joseph County", year = 2021)
mapview(tracts,  zcol = "AWATER", legend = TRUE, col.regions = pal(44)) # colors using a variety of colors
mapview(tracts,  zcol = "AWATER", legend = TRUE) # colors also using a variety of colors
mapview(tracts,  zcol = "AWATER", legend = TRUE, col.regions = "red") # colors everything just red
```

How do I set it so it's just red but at a gradient?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Leaflet's Color Mapping functions. You can specify an already created colour palette, or create your own.

```
tracts <- tracts("IN", "St. Joseph County", year = 2021)
reds = colorBin(palette = "Reds", domain = NULL)
mapview(tracts, zcol="AWATER", col.regions = reds(tracts$AWATER), at=seq(0, 1500000, 200000))
```

[image: Bad colours]

That is a step in the right direction, but you probably noticed a few errors such as the colors are divergent from the middle, and there appears to be a tract without a colour.

You probably want something more along the lines of what the colorRampPalette function can do:

```
tracts <- tracts("IN", "St. Joseph County", year = 2021)
reds = colorRampPalette(c('pink', 'dark red'))
mapview(tracts, zcol="AWATER", col.regions = reds, at=seq(0, 2514920, 500000))
```

[image: Better colours]

You should be able to get a decent looking map by playing around with the palette values as well as the at=seq() parameters.